# Windows 10 apps "Sort by Install Date" are not sorted by time

Tags: windows-7, installation, sorting

In all previous versions of Windows, when you sorted the installed programs by "date installed," it would sort them exactly like that - by date and TIME installed.

In Windows 10, it takes all the apps that were installed on a particular day and then sorts THOSE by name. Yesterday I installed many programs (new windows installation) and one of the apps also installed some extra stuff I don't want but I have no idea what. Just by sorting by "install date" doesn't help because it's now sorted by name on yesterday's date, along with the other 50 things I installed yesterday.

Trying to go to "Program Files" and "Program Files(86)" and sorting there by date created is not a solution because some programs don't get installed there.

Is there a way to sort the apps by the EXACT date and time they were installed without using 3rd party software like "IObit Uninstaller?"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I just found out that there is another way to access the "Uninstall or change a program" window, which works like the older Windows versions, and that is via the control panel\Programs and Features. Now I can sort by date installed correctly.

Comment: Why the vote-down? Do you have another way?

Comment: Super answer! I have no idea why this option is not the default approach - I have lost so much time on the dumb "sort by day only, screw time" option.